How to scale my AWS EC2 instance using SQS backlogs in AWS cloudwatch?
I have an application which will consume the incoming requests from AWS SQS and perform the task on EC2 instance and give it back to my customer. When I try to use AWS AutoScaling by default it only shows to scaling with basic metrics like CPU metrics.
I've tried to scale manually but its not feasible for me, so I need help with setting up an auto scaling that will automatically scale based on my Queues in my SQS as my backlog for one EC2 instance is 5 messages it should scale with that

Have you tried to create an scaling policy with SQS's number of available messages and set the auto scaling?
I've already wrote a blog for this you can find it here. EC2 scaling with SQS

can you help me with steps for that ?

yes sure, editing my anwer above

This was exactly what I was looking for thanks

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
